# flex4 LinkElement underline

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How can I remove the underline when using LinkElement Class in Flex4? 
This problem has troubled me for days. Like this:

```
var a:LinkElement = new LinkElement();
var s:Span = new Span();
s.text = 'Goto';
a.addChild(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

don't know if this may help you, the textflow has an propertie for linkstyle 
in flash. this only works in flash when the htmltext is set before the style is applied

maybe it helps you to find an solution

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3358839